# C# handling user interaction in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, observer-pattern

I have an implemented MVC Pattern and am thinking about Error handling and catching user decissions.

My current approach is:
create for every decissiontype an Event Hook and let the GUI View (in my case the Form) create a specific User interaction (like a console output or MessageBox)

My Question: It seems a bit strange, is there a better approach to do that?
If not, how should the class `UserDecission` be designed to handle most user interaction cases?

simple Example: the View has registered to `AskUser` and calls `SaveFile()`

```
public class UserDecission
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Asked to the user, might be a placeholder constant, which the gui can make "pretty"(Display a MessageBox to the user)
    /// </summary>
    public string Question { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// return value
    /// </summary>
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
public interface IModel
{
    void SaveFile(string filename);
    EventHandler<UserDecission> AskUser { get; set; }
}
public class Model : IModel
{
    public EventHandler<UserDecission> AskUser { get; set; }
    public void SaveFile(string filename)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            UserDecission decission = new UserDecission() { Question = "FileExistsOverwrite" };
            AskUser?.Invoke(this, decission);
            if (!decission.Answer.Equals("Yes"))
                return;
            //... Do the saving here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `EventHandler<T>` in this case, because this is not technically an event, but rather a custom delegate type:

```
public delegate string UserPromptHandler( string question );
```

That will make the code look more clear, because the result is actually returned to you and there is no unnecessary "sender", etc. You can also force the user of your class to provide the handler in the class constructor to be sure you the handler exists.

Comment: The EventHandler has the feature, that the observer doesnt need to cache the model, it can cast sender to IModel and retrieve additional context Information (in a more complex case), but then i could use a custom class to replace the ```string``` datatype:
```public delegate string UserPromptHandler( ComplexClass question );```